# what does different values in cv2.waitkey() means?

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, opencv

I am learning cv2, I came across this code snippet. What exactly it is doing?

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Answer (score 6):

It waits up to 1 millisecond for the user to press a key. It then takes the value of the key read, and ANDs it with `0xFF` which masks off (removes) anything above the bottom 8-bits and compares the result of that with the ASCII code for the letter `q` which would mean the user has decided to quit by pressing `q` on the keyboard.

During that time, it also updates and refreshes any OpenCV windows that are currently displaying images by responding to display events.

In short, it waits for up to 1 ms for a keypress and then checks if `quit` was pressed.

Comment: Thank you captain.